# Where can I find oracle lab files?

Tags: oracle

When I was a student we studied Oracle Database 10g: SQL and PL/SQL textbooks. At that time I asked the lecturer if I can take lab files. And he told me that they are freely available at Oracle website. But now I can't find them. I mean a filled database. At that time it contained data about King, Kochar, De Haan etc and about their departments.

Any Oracle version would suit. 10g would be fine. And newer filed would be ok as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean sample data? It should come in the `SCOTT` and `HR` (for instance) schemas on your actual database.

Comment: Yes, sample data. Could you give me a direct link to any?

Comment: You should have some on your database already...

Comment: I have never installed Oracle. You mean a demo base will be preinstalled when I install oracle database (I mean that version for non commercial use)?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/scripts.htm), though it's [locked by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_connecting.htm#TDDDG12510).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install the sample schemas when you initially create the database or you can install them afterwards if the database already exists.

First you can try looking in $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/.  The sample schema install scripts should be in there.

If you need to download them from Oracle, head to their website under the Downloads section for Oracle Database, and select the version and platform you are using currently.  The example schemas are in the Oracle Database Examples zip file.

There should be similar instructions for each version, but the link to 11g is below.

Oracle® Database Sample Schemas 11g Release 2 (11.2)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm